# Save multiple rows from HTML table that are checked to a List?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have an HTML table with a checkmark next to each row. I also have a button at the top that is "Get Selected". What I want to be able to do is:

- Select multiple rows
- Click the "Get Selected" button
- Create a list of the selected rows that gets returned to a Python file, where functions will modify it, then a new table is created of those modifications.

HTML File

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <body> 
    <input type="button" value="Get Selected" onclick = GetChecked() />
        <table id="movies" class="table" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Select</th>
                  <th>Title</th>
                  <th>Year</th>
                  <th>Directors</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for item in data %}
              <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id = "checkbx" name="select"></td>
                    <td>{{item[0]}}</td>
                    <td>{{item[1]}}</td>
                    <td class="directors">{{item[2]}}</td>
              </tr>
              {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
            </table>
    </body> 
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

Python File

```python
@app.route("/recc")
def recc():
    df = f.movieTable()
    li = df.values.tolist()
    return render_template("recc.html", data=li)
```

Table Appearance Before Selecting:
[image]

I have not been able to get anything to work when clicking the Get Selected button. Not even an alert message, which I have tried on Safari and Chrome.

This is my most recent script attempt in the HTML file, but I don't know how I would return selectedMovies to the Python file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetSelected() {
        var grid = document.getElementById("movies");
 
        var checkBoxes = grid.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
        var selectedMovies =  []
 
        for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
            if (checkBoxes[i].checked) {
                var row = checkBoxes[i].parentNode.parentNode;
                selectedMovies.push(row)
            }
        }
        return selectedMovies;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The caller of `GetSelected()` should create an array of objects that contain the data from those rows. Then it can send this as JSON to Python using AJAX.

Comment: @Barmar So, I am able to create an array of the data, and that array is stored on the HTML file (recc.html). I am also able to make it a JSON variable. I want to be able to use that array on another file in the directory called "f.py." (Python file). I am using VSCode, but not sure how I would do this. You said AJAX, but all I have seen is how to read things from URLs. Am I able to use AJAX in the python file? I also do not know how to save the JSON file to my directory, like how Python has "file.write."

Comment: AJAX is used to send requests from the browser to the server. The Flask code on the server receives this request and saves the data to a JSON file.